# RPC timeout in cqlsh - Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, timeout, cql

I have 5 nodes in my ring with `SimpleTopologyStrategy` and `replication_factor=3`. I inserted 1M  rows using stress tool . When am trying to read the row count in cqlsh using

```
SELECT  count(*) FROM  Keyspace1.Standard1 limit 1000000;
```

It fails with error:

> Request did not complete within rpc_timeout.

It fetches for limit 100000. Fails even for 500000.
All my nodes are up. Do I need to increase the `rpc_timeout`?

Please help.

Comment: Since there are people I work with who are forwarding this post to me as something they want done, I feel compelled to mention that **increasing the query timeouts in a production cluster is a terrible, terrible idea.**

Answer (score 14):

You get this error because the request is timing out on the server side. One should know that this is a very expensive operation in Cassandra as others have pointed out.

Still, if you really want to do this you should update your `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` file and change the `range_request_timeout_in_ms` parameter. This will be valid for all your range queries.

Example to set a 40 second timeout:

```
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 40000
```

You will probably have to adjust at the client side as well. When using `cqlsh` as a client this is accomplished by creating/updating your configuration file for cqlsh under `~/.cassandra/cqlshrc` and add the `client_timeout` parameter to the `connection` section.

Example to set a 40 second timeout:

```
[connection]
client_timeout=40
```

Answer (score 6):

It takes a long time to read in 1M rows so that is probably why it is timing out.  You shouldn't use count like this, it is very expensive since it has to read all the data.  Use Cassandra counters if you need to count lots of items.

You should also check your Cassandra logs to confirm there aren't any other issues - sometimes exceptions in Cassandra lead to timeouts on the client.

Answer (score 2):

If you can live with an approximate row count, take a look at this answer to [Row count of a column family in Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447193/58994).