# Apache Spark SQL is taking forever to count billion rows from Cassandra?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have the following code

I invoke spark-shell as follows

```
./spark-shell --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=170.99.99.134 --executor-memory 15G --executor-cores 12 --conf spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb=67108864
```

code

```scala
scala> val df = spark.sql("SELECT test from hello") // Billion rows in hello and test column is 1KB

df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [test: binary]

scala> df.count

[Stage 0:>   (0 + 2) / 13] // I dont know what these numbers mean precisely.
```

If I invoke spark-shell as follows

```
./spark-shell --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=170.99.99.134
```

code

```scala
val df = spark.sql("SELECT test from hello") // This has about billion rows

scala> df.count


[Stage 0:=>  (686 + 2) / 24686] // What are these numbers precisely?
```

Both of these versions didn't work Spark keeps running forever and I have been waiting for more than 15 mins and no response. Any ideas on what could be wrong and how to fix this?

I am using Spark 2.0.2
and spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.0.0-M3.jar

Comment: With a billion rows you probably would have had to wait 2 or 3 hours to get the approximate answer.

Answer (score 4):

`Dataset.count` is slow because it is not very smart when it comes to external data sources. It rewrites query as (it is good):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table
```

but instead of pushing `COUNT` down it just executes :

```
SELECT 1 FROM table
```

against the source (it'll fetch a billion ones in your case) and then aggregates locally to get the final result. Numbers you see are tasks counters.

There is an optimized `cassandraCount` operation on `CassandraRDD`:

```
sc.cassandraTable(keyspace, table).cassandraCount
```

More about server side operations can be found in [the documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md).