# How to fix read timeout exception in spark Cassandra connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, azure-databricks

I am using spark 2.4 and scala 2.11 in azure databricks platform, DSE 6.0.7 and spark cassandra connector version 2.4.0

I am getting below error while getting the count for one of my table which has around ~100Million records. Exact row count is required for one of the applications. Below is my code -

```
val count = spark.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .option("table", tableName)
  .option("keyspace", keyspace)
  .load()
  .count()
```

Below is exception -

```
java.io.IOException: Exception during execution of SELECT count(*) FROM "mykeyspace"."mytable" WHERE token("id") > ? AND token("id") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: [/host:9042] Timed out waiting for server response
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:350)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$17.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:367)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$17.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:367)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:634)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:139)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:497)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1432)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:503)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [/host:9042] Timed out waiting for server response
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Spark SQL is taking forever to count billion rows from Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40778936/apache-spark-sql-is-taking-forever-to-count-billion-rows-from-cassandra)

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40778936/apache-spark-sql-is-taking-forever-to-count-billion-rows-from-cassandra

Comment: @Chandra How are you connecting to Cassandra from databricks notebook?